# React(Native) setState from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having problems updating the React local state from a child component.

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-sanderson-try90) my reproducible code.

Basically there are 3 tabs, the active one is the second one. When you click on another tabs, the state is not updated correctly. What am I missing?

This is not really a React Native related question, it's simply a React related.

Note: I can't restructure the entire component, so I can't transform it to a function component and so I can't use hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using onPress with wrong params. You just update like this:

```
onPress={() => onPress(tabKey)}
```